# Vectors under Galilean transformation

Tags: vectors, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

Acceleration and speed are both vectors. The former is invariant under boosts, while the latter is not. Why are vectors defined solely on the way they change under rotations and not under Galilean transformations as well? Isn't it a weak point to write laws using mathematical objects that are well-defined only with respect to some transormations between inertial frames?

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, your first sentence is unrelated to your question? Do you mean why are transformations defined as how they change under rotations? I mean, acceleration isn't a defined as a vector that rotates? It is defined as the vector which is the derivative of the velocity with respect to time?

Comment: You are right: I might have been a bit cryptic. In Newtonian mechanics, a vector is a set of 3 components that under a rotation of the frame of reference changes accordingly to v = Rv, where R is a matrix representing the rotation. Therefore, speed and acceleration are vectors. Yet, if we consider a boost, acceleration is invariant under that transformation but speed is not (its magnitude varies from one frame to the other, so the vector is not the same).

Comment: How do you define a boost?

Comment: @R.W.Bird With a 4×4 matrix, similarly to the matrix of a Lorentz transformation, the time coordinate being independent of the other three.

Comment: @Simone In your formula $v \neq Rv$, $v_\alpha = Rv$. They're not both the same vector $v$, they're both 2 distinct vectors. Also, Galilean transformations are linear boosts by a constant. Derivatives are unaffected by constants hence acceleration is invariant. Vectors in general, as mathematical objects have nothing to do with specific reference frames. Only specific vectors do. Unless I've misunderstood what you are trying to ask?

Answer (score 0):

This question is resolved in relativity. Galilean transformation applies to 3-vectors, in relativity we use 4-vectors and describe boosts with Lorentz transformation. In general relativity, physical laws written in terms of vectors and tensors are unchanged in all frames, not just in inertial frames.